# Finding $\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{e^{1/x}}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am trying to find the following limit
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{e^{1/x}}{x}
$$

As $x$ approaches $0$ from the left I see that both the numerator and denominator approach $0$. So this seems like a standard L'Hopital's rule. But when I apply this, then I get
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{e^{1/x}}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{e^{1/x}(-1/x^2)}{1} = \lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{e^{1/x}}{-x^2}
$$
So this doesn't seem to help much. I am a bit lost.

Comment: from the left the Limit is Zero.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/718627) answer might help.

Comment: The limit will be 0 since $e^{-1/x}$ approaches 0 exponentially faster than $1/x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by $x=-\frac1y$ with $y \to +\infty$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{e^{1/x}}{x}=\lim_{y\to +\infty} -ye^{-y}=\lim_{y\to \infty} -\frac{y}{e^{y}}=0$$

indeed eventually $e^y>y^2$ and

$$\frac{y}{e^{y}}<\frac{y}{y^2}=\frac1y\to0$$

Comment: for $\lim_{y\to \infty} \frac{-y}{e^y}$ I guess I could then use L'Hopital?

Comment: @JohnDoe You can but as gimusi as has stated, $e^y >> y^2$ as $y -> \inf$

Comment: @JohnDoe Yes of course but I suggest to avoid the use of l'Hopital to solve limits, it is more instructive to become aware with the use of others method such standard limits, inequalities and squeeze theorem.

Comment: Hmm looks just like my previous answer.

Comment: @Tal-Botvinnik Yes same idea for the subsitution but conclusion by squeeze theorem.

Comment: @Tal-Botvinnik What do you mean with "my previous answer"?

Comment: Well you could have suggested that in a comment, but that's ok

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$\cfrac{\cfrac{1}{x}}{\cfrac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}}$ Now apply L-Hospital

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=-1/x$, then your limit gives
$$-\lim_{y\to\infty}ye^{-y}=-\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{y}{e^y}=0$$
by l'Hopital's rule